# Using Powershell command New-AUDser to set -HomeDrive and -HomeDirectory

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I'm trying to create a new user in AD with the New-ADUser command.
When i look in the Users and Computers gui, all the parameters i've passed through powershell, is populated to correct fields, including HomeDrive and HomeDirectory.

However, the folder is not created on the share server, but when setting parameters manually in AD gui, the folder is created.

So my question(s) is/are, the powershell command, is it passed to Active Directory and Active Directory then handles the rest?

Or is powershell handling the entire thing and also passing the directory commands by itself?

P.s
Active Directory is on server1(Windows 2008 R2) and usershares is on server2(Windows Server 2003).

I've verified that the Permissions ar correct as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555046

Thanks to anyone who possibly can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory doesn't take care of creating the homedir, it's the ADUC console that does the work.

So if you want to do it via Powershell you need to do it "manually" (create the folder with powershell)

Comment: Thanks, ill do that. Found this http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/2012/02/29/setting-a-users-home-directory.aspx It seems this is the way to go then.